# Anyone come across a js calendar that can show custom intervals as rows with vertical layout in resource planner view/mode?

Tags: javascript, scheduling, resource-management, sharepoint

Looking to generate a calendar similar to the one here based on SharePoint list items. Open to using Google Charts or FullCalendar. Would like to be able to set scroll window size in weeks or months. Additional list columns include dates that would feed into hover text. I could code this all by hand in javascript, but would prefer to use a library that's already built if possible. Haven't found any built-in layouts for this sort of view in either desired library. Found some code forks, but those also still didn't seem to reflect as seen here.

Could also settle for a horizontal layout, but this view for me seems to fit the most amount of info into a printable area/layout in an easy to manage size.

[image: resource schedule vertical layout by week]

Comment: I'm aware it's been a long time, but what did you end up using for this?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

### FullCalendar + Scheduler (open source)

What comes really close is I think the [Scheduler add-on](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) for [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). In December 2018, a major rework "version 4" was released in alpha state. And, it's all open source :-)

Differences to your ideal case:

- Time is on the horizontal axis, not the vertical.
- The largest scroll window size that I have seen is is "day". However, this may just be a configuration matter, as the [custom scale demo](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/scale.html) shows it can be changed between quarterly, hourly and days already. Otherwise, adding "week" to that might be an acceptable effort.

### DHTMLX Scheduler (commercial)

The one alternative component I know for this is [DHTMLX Scheduler](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/index.html). It comes with several "views", some of which are in the GPL version and some only in the [commercial version](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/licenses.shtml).

Unfortunately for your case, the view that would suit your needs is only available in the commercial version.

Anyway, here's how you would do it: choose [Timeline View](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html). Time is on the horizontal axis, not the vertical as would be your ideal case. But you can for sure set your scroll window size to weeks: it's `x_unit: "week"` in [createTimelineView()](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_createtimelineview.html).

(There is also [Units View](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/units_view.html), but seemingly it always has hours on one axis and [this cannot be changed](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_createunitsview.html).)